# sorting with jquery,ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this js script:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.fancybox',
    update: function(e, ui) {
        debugger;
        order= $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el) {
            return el.id;

        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "inc/ajax/sortable/update.php",
            data: { 'order':order },

            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },

            error: function (xhr, err) {
                 alert("readyState: " +    xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                 alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
         });
    }
});
```

and 2 files for php

here I set the value for order variable:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['order']);
unset($_SESSION['ordine']);
unset($_SESSION['ordine']);
foreach($_POST['order'] as $val) {

print_r($_SESSION['order'][]=$val); 

}
```

here I need to update:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['order'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['order']);
    foreach($_SESSION['img'] as $key=>$val) {

        echo $_SESSION['order'][$key]."  pentru ".$val."\n";
        $sql="UPDATE `anunturi_images` SET `sort`=:i WHERE `id_imag`=:val" ;
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $data = array(':i'=>$_SESSION['order'][$key],':val'=>$val);         
        $stmt->execute($data);

    }
}
```

The problem is:

When I sort twice then the value for order variable i ok but if I sort only one the order variable is the initial order.

how can i set the order variable correctly when i sort only one time.

Comment: You are not fetching updated records after executing sql (update).

Comment: can you be  more expicit?